# Forced Orr-Sommerfeld problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am writing to ask you a hint on how to solve a forced Orr-Sommerfeld problem.
Basically I have a system like this

$(C_1\alpha^2 + C_2\alpha + C_0)q(x) = F(x)$

q(x) is the state vector and C are constant matrices. Without F(x), which is the forcing term, it would be a non linear eigenvalue problem. Do you have any suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: {Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).